# Attachement in soapUI

Tags: groovy, base64, soapui

I am getting a response which contains a text file as an attachment but I am not able see that attachment in soapUI attachment tab even I changed MTOM true.Can I get this attachment by writing some groovy?

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
  <ns1:getFileResponse xmlns:ns1="urn:getfile1">
     <return xsi:type="xsd:base64Binary">PD9waHANCiRoYW5kbGUgPSBmb3BlbigiQzovL3hhbXBwLy9odGRvY3MvL3JldGFpbC8vdGVzdC5waHAiLCAiciIpOw0KPz4NCg==</return>
  </ns1:getFileResponse>
```

Answer (score 1):

See answers for the very same question at SoapUI support forum:
https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Saving-attachments-automatically/m-p/880#U880

Comment: Looks above link is not available any more. I found [here](http://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/Saving-attachments-automatically/m-p/880#U880) a working one.